# Why is "Me help him out?" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I found this sentence while I was looking up the word "[perish](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/perish)":

> What? **Me help him out?** Perish the thought.

Shouldn't it be the following?

> What? **I help him out?** Perish the thought.

Comment: In your second sentence, it should be *I* ***should*** *help him out?* if it's to be more easily understood. However, that aside, both constructions are fine—unless you want to get into a detailed analysis of the technical grammar.

Answer (score 1):

It does look odd. To understand this you first need to note that these are not complete sentences. Ignoring the last part, it has the same structure as

> What? A cat?

Which we understand to mean:

> What is it? Is it a cat?

The last part "Me help him out" is not a complete sentence, but reduced from the end of something like "Is it me who should help him out".

In modern English the tendency is to use "me" such situations; the pronoun is not acting a subject in a complete clause.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't.

That should have been "What, me? Help him out? Perish the thought!"

D'you see the difference? –